# External hard disk with broken permissions, no security tab in explorer

Tags: windows-7

I have an external usb hard disk, connected to my windows 7 machine as drive f. It is formatted with ntfs, and everything worked fine for a while. Then I used cygwin to copy the contents of another external hard disk into its root, and since then, things have been screwy:

- I can't create new files on the disk in some places.
- the folders "$recycle.bin" and "system volume information" are both visible
- explorer does not show the security tab for files and folders on the drive.

I've tried using "takeown  /f   f:\   /a   /r   /d y" and "icacls f:\  /t /c /grant administrators:F  System:F  everyone:F" , but neither had any effect. How can I fix this, preferably without reformatting it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look the 3rd tool that specified to this type of issue, Permissions Time Machine - *(google for download link)*

Try it if other method failed on your previous attempts.

Permissions Time Machine is a tool to fix Windows permissions, remove "Access Is Denied" error message, and restore all access permissions to:

1. Partitions.
2. Folders (Local/Remote Share).
3. Files(Local/Remote Share).
4. Registry keys.
5. Windows Services (Local/Remote Share).
6. Windows Printers (Local/Remote Share).
7. System Process
8. WMI Objects.

> Main Features :
>
> - Reset Or Restore Access Permissions By One Click.
> - Restore Access To
>   Any User Account Or Groups. etc...